# Как запустить крон в ларавел

Tags: laravel, cron

Подскажите, как запустить крон на isp manager Пробовал: wget -O /dev/null -q "domen/artisan schedule:run" не работает. В этом еще сильно новичек.

Или как его еще можно вызвать? Мне его хоть как то дернуть бы)))

Answer (score 0):

Тут вопрос не в самом laravel, а в администрировании сервера. По опыту желательно выполнять консольные задачи от имени пользователя, от имени которого также веб часть работает (nginx+php-fpm или другие связки)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]